# MS Access issue

Tags: databases, excel

I have a database that I send to an excel  sheet that auto populates some field in a report with calculations that I need. There are several users and the excel sheet cannot be open at multiple times which has become an issue, after the data is submitted in the database the excel doesn't come up which the users need to print out every time. 
My question is, how can I make the excel read only so that they can just print and save the document while multiple users being in the excel since it is read only. 
The problem with this has become the fact that access sees the file as already open and doesn't write the data. Is there a solution without me making a report in access.

Thanks

Comment: I fear this isn't the right site for this question. Perhaps you should try: https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

Instead  of sending data to Excel, Try to create  a Query that populates data in Access

Then From Excel  use Data-From Access to import the data into Excel.

Users can hit refresh data (or you can put a Macro to do that every time user opens the file) data from Access  will be in Excel.

Comment: Multiple users wouldn't be able to use that excel at the sane time though.

Comment: You need  a shared workbook that read data  from that Excel file (linked one) because linked Excel file can not be shared